# Native Code Library not found

Tags: macos, hadoop2

I have installed Hadoop-2.6.0 in Mac OS (10.11.*)
Have followed the procedure given in the link
http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html

While Starting NameNode and DataNode

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Am getting the following two errors.

1. Not able to recognize the native-hadoop Libray
2. SSH to port connected 22 failed

> Starting secondary namenodes [2016-02-15 22:46:36,600 WARN  [main]
>   util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:(62)) - Unable to
>   load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java
>   classes where applicable  0.0.0.0]
>
> ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused
>
> JPS gives me
>
> 7102 Jps

Kindly help me resolving it

## Error Details

Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
 and 
ssh: connect to host to port 22: Connection refused

Below are the configurations am using

## Hadoop-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/library/hadoop-2.6.0/

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/Library/hadoop-2.6.0/


export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

## Profile :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/Library/hadoop-2.6.0
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop/
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Please note I have went thru multiple blogs and not able to resolve it out.
Have enabled the Remote Sharing in System Preferences too

Answer (score 1):

I have got this fixed by following the below link 
http://amodernstory.com/2014/09/23/installing-hadoop-on-mac-osx-yosemite/

However the differences I noticed are
1) I was using OS El Capitan
2) Hadoop-env-sh has

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.security.krb5.realm= -Djava.security.krb5.kdc="
```

If some one gets more clarity please post here for better understanding